# can a pandas.Period represent an arbitrary time span?

Tags: python, pandas

**Edit: the (puzzling) behavior below was for pandas 0.17.1.  It appears fixed in 0.18.1.**

Is there a way to represent an arbitrary time span with a `pandas.Period`?

Specifically, I was trying to contrive a `pandas.Period()` to represent an arbitrary *n*-day span (with the goal of making a multi-year `Period`).

I tried a few things, and it seems that playing with the `freq` argument gets me more or less what I want.  However, I was surprised by the unexpected `end_time` of the period in the case of the `freq` argument having a multiplier (as in `freq='2D'`).

```
import pandas as pd

p = pd.Period(1970, freq='2D')
p  # Period('1970-01-01', '2D')

p.start_time  # Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00')
p.end_time    # Timestamp('1970-01-04 23:59:59.999999999')
p.end_time - p.start_time
# Timedelta('3 days 23:59:59.999999')
```

Why? That's 4 days, not 2.

However:

```
p+1  # Period('1970-01-03', '2D')
(p+1).start_time  # Timestamp('1970-01-03 00:00:00')
```

So, `(p+1)` gives me the expected (a period starting 2 days after `p`'s start).

But what's the deal with `end_time`?  What's the relationship between `freq='nD'` to actual duration in days?

```
def actual_span(n, unit='D'):
    p = pd.Period(1970, freq='{}{}'.format(n, unit))
    return p.end_time + pd.Timedelta(1) - p.start_time

x = pd.DataFrame({'d': range(1, 10)})
x['span'] = x.n.apply(actual_span)
print(x.set_index('n'))

#      span
# n        
# 1  1 days
# 2  4 days
# 3  9 days
# 4 16 days
# 5 25 days
# 6 36 days
# 7 49 days
# 8 64 days
# 9 81 days
```

Why is it the square of the requested number of days?

Note that `(p+1).start_time` is correct (gives us `n` days).

<sub>Small print: Python 3.51, Pandas <s>0.18.1</s> *correction:* 0.17.1.</sub>

Comment: `pd.Period(1970, freq='2D')` has the expected `start_time` and `end_time` for me, also using Pandas 0.18.1.  Maybe try restarting your interpreter, and run the first bit of code you posted again to verify that you're still getting the unexpected output?

Comment: @root Thanks! Indeed, I was on a machine that had an older (0.17.1) version that the one I normally use. I could reproduce it in another interpreter, but after update of pandas to 0.18.1, it seems fixed.

Comment: @root: If you care to leave your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.Period(1970, freq='2D')` has the expected `start_time` and `end_time` for me, also using Pandas 0.18.1. Maybe try restarting your interpreter, and run the first bit of code you posted again to verify that you're still getting the unexpected output?